Calculate rolling adjusted date based on date from parent row - lag / recursion
Given the data set below, I need to calculate a rolling AdjustedHireByDate. Each AdjustedHireByDate should be @NumWeeks weeks from the previous row's AdjustedHireByDate (if they have the same parent) unless the PreviousHireDate on the current row is not null. If PreviousHireDate is not null, use the PreviousHireDate to calculate the AdjustedHireByDate for the given row. This all stems from an initial parent record who's HireByDate does not change (unless it has a HireDate of course).
Sql Fiddle
-- INIT database
CREATE TABLE Vacancy 
(
    ParentID INT NOT NULL,
    PreviousID INT NOT NULL,
    CurrentID INT NOT NULL,
    PreviousHireByDate DATE NOT NULL,
    PreviousHireDate DATE NULL
);

INSERT INTO Vacancy (ParentID, PreviousID, CurrentID, PreviousHireByDate, PreviousHireDate) 
VALUES (3752, 3752, 3753, '2024-11-18', NULL),
       (3752, 3753, 3754, '2025-02-24', NULL),
       (3752, 3754, 3973, '2025-06-02', NULL),
       (3752, 3973, 4391, '2025-09-08', NULL),
       (3752, 4391, 4650, '2025-12-15', NULL),
       (3957, 3957, 3958, '2024-10-21', '2024-10-28'),
       (3957, 3958, 3959, '2025-02-02', NULL),
       (3957, 3959, 3960, '2025-06-23', NULL),
       (3957, 3960, 4146, '2025-09-15', '2025-08-04'),
       (3957, 4146, 4623, '2025-12-22', NULL);




ParentID
PreviousId
CurrentId
PreviousHireByDate
PreviousHireDate




3752
3752
3753
2024-11-18
NULL


3752
3753
3754
2025-02-24
NULL


3752
3754
3973
2025-06-02
NULL


3752
3973
4391
2025-09-08
NULL


3752
4391
4650
2025-12-15
NULL


3957
3957
3958
2024-10-28
2024-10-28


3957
3958
3959
2025-02-02
NULL


3957
3959
3960
2025-06-23
NULL


3957
3960
4146
2025-09-15
2025-08-04


3957
4146
4623
2025-12-22
NULL



Desired output given the above data set and using @NumWeeks = 2 (note this will usually be 8-24 weeks, but for simpler math/validation using a simpler number so the dates may seem to be getting adjusted more significantly than they will in practice.):



ParentID
PreviousId
CurrentId
PreviousHireByDate
PreviousHireDate
AdjustedHireByDate




3752
3752
3753
2024-11-18
NULL
2024-12-02


3752
3753
3754
2025-02-24
NULL
2024-12-16


3752
3754
3973
2025-06-02
NULL
2024-12-30


3752
3973
4391
2025-09-08
NULL
2025-01-13


3752
4391
4650
2025-12-15
NULL
2025-01-27


3957
3957
3958
2024-10-21
2024-10-28
2024-11-11


3957
3958
3959
2025-02-02
NULL
2024-11-25


3957
3959
3960
2025-06-23
NULL
2024-12-09


3957
3960
4146
2025-09-15
2025-08-04
2025-08-18


3957
4146
4623
2025-12-22
NULL
2025-09-01



Current select is
DECLARE @NumWeeks SMALLINT = 2;

WITH InitialHireByDate AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        CASE 
            WHEN ParentID = PreviousID 
                THEN COALESCE(PreviousHireDate, PreviousHireByDate) 
            ELSE NULL
        END AS AdjustedHireByDate 
    FROM 
        Vacancy
),
LaggedHireByDate AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ParentID,
        PreviousID,
        CurrentID,
        PreviousHireDate,
        PreviousHireByDate,
        DATEADD(WEEK, @NumWeeks, 
                COALESCE(PreviousHireDate,   
                         LAG(AdjustedHireByDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY PreviousID ASC)
                        )) AS AdjustedHireByDate
    FROM 
        InitialHireByDate
)
SELECT * 
FROM LaggedHireByDate

